# Azure Function App Unable to get Connection String : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: c#, azure-functions, connection-string, appsettings

I have an Azure Function with DDD Architecture. My project structure looks like this: [image]

`local.settings.json` file Looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ServiceBusConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://sb.servicebus.windows.net/;*****"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:*************"
  }
}
```

And my `appsettings.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
     "DefaultConnection": "*******"
  }
}
```

And `ApplicationDbContextFactory` file looks like this :

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting this error when running locally ? Connection strings are to be stored in `app settings`,  but when in production, it is better to be in Azure Key vault.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran locally it's working fine.

Comment: In the Azure portal, have you created this `DefaultConnection`  under Configuration blade ? Follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran yeah. I've added all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the specify the connection string prefix (see documentation):

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CUSTOMCONNSTR_DefaultConnection");
```

This prefix classification is:

CUSTOMCONNSTR_ => Custom provider

MYSQLCONNSTR_ => MySQL

SQLAZURECONNSTR_ => Azure SQL Database

SQLCONNSTR_ => SQL Server

Credit goes to the people in this post:

[Get Connection String in Azure Function v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406026/get-connection-string-in-azure-function-v3)

Answer (score 3):

This is an annoying issue. Here are my findings:

### Option 1:

**local.settings.json**

add your connection strings to the Values section with [appropriate prefixes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#variable-prefixes)
then get them in your function app by simply calling

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("yourConnString")
```

**Azure App (or Function, etc.) Configuration**

Add the same values to the ConnectionStrings section but without the prefixes

### Option 2:

**local.settings.json**

add your connection strings to the ConnectionStrings section with [appropriate prefixes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#variable-prefixes)
then get them in your function app by calling

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:yourConnString")
```

Notice the *ConnectionStrings* prefix! This will work locally but not in Azure because of that extra *ConnectionStrings* prefix. Can be addressed with some [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation) though.

**Azure App (or Function, etc.) Configuration**

Add the same values to the ConnectionStrings section but without the prefixes

### Option 3:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980684/8833279) on how to inject IConfiguration to read the conn strings like

```
configuration.GetConnectionString("yourConnString")
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction, you can initialize the Configuration in Startup

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Use below code in Unit tests Init to inject the local settings file

```
        IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        // Duplicate here any configuration sources you use.
        configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\local.settings.json");
        configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
```